# I want to appoint array in insert sentence

Tags: python, orientdb

I use pyorient.
The following things want to make it, but can register nothing.

```
lst = ['10', '20', '30']
var = 2016
client.command("insert into class1 (datet, price) values(var, lst[0])")
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
lst = ['10', '20', '30']
var = 2016

client.command("insert into class1 set datet='%d', price='%s'" % (var,lst[0]));
```

or

```
client.command("insert into class1 (datet,price) values ('%d','%s')" % (var,lst[0]))
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: I appreciate your kind response.Thx!